# Conditional artifact resolution in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project with three sub-projects `client`, `common`, and `server`.
In this `client` and `common` are simple libraries while `server` is a spring boot application.

Now I recently upgraded my gradle version from 5.x to 6.9 (still old, I know). As I found out a bit later when trying to publish artifacts it couldn't find the server artifact anymore as the detection for stale artifacts had been improved. This is my publication block:

```
subprojects {
    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that for spring boot I simply need to replace `from components.java` with `artifact tasks.named('bootJar')` and that I could overwrite this in the `build.gradle` of my `server` subproject, however I would like gradle to auto detect which artifact to use.

I already tried

```
if(plugins.hasPlugin('org.springframework.boot')) {
    artifact tasks.named('bootJar')
} else {
    from components.java
}
```

As this is evaluated on the root project and not sub project it is not evaluated as I would like. Is there a way to get such a conditional artifact detection working in gradle or do I have to override the artifact to publish in my sub project?